# Best method to save UITextField test: textFieldShouldReturn or textFieldDidEndEditing

Tags: ios

my objective simply to save text on UITextField after user click done button on keyboard. I could either do this in extFieldShouldReturn or textFieldDidEndEditing: does it make any difference ? or there a better approach ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

textFieldShouldReturn is only called if the user presses the return key. If the keyboard is dismissed due to some other reason such as the user selecting another field, or switching views to another screen, it won't be but textFieldDidEndEditing will be.

The best approach is to use textFieldShouldReturn to resign the responder (hide the keyboard) like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //hide the keyboard
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    //return NO or YES, it doesn't matter
    return YES;
}
```

When the keyboard closes, textFieldDidEndEditing will be called. You can then use textFieldDidEndEditing to do something with the text:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //do something with the text
}
```

But if you actually want to perform the action only when the user explicitly presses the "go" or "send" or "search" (or whatever) button on the keyboard, then you should put that handler in the textFieldShouldReturn method instead, like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //hide the keyboard
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    //submit my form
    [self submitFormActionOrWhatever];

    //return NO or YES, it doesn't matter
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: does this mean that I should use textFieldDidEndEditing or there a better approach?

Comment: Thanks.. i would like to save the text even if user didn't hit "Done" button, even if for example user press the "Home" button. I understood from your answer I should use "textFieldShouldReturn", right?

Comment: No. You should use textFieldDidEndEditing.

Comment: +1 for good explanation. One gotcha to look out for: this requires that the class in which you're adding these methods is a UITextFieldDelegate (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818960/keyboard-wont-close-with-uitextfield)

Comment: hi, I am trying your first example but I see that it invokes the method BEFORE actually closing the keyboard. How can I close the keyboard and then invoke the method?

Comment: If you want to do something when the keyboard is hidden (as opposed to when a field loses firstResponder status) then you're better off using the UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, which you can observe using NSNotificationCenter.