# Keyboard won't close with UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, keyboard, uitextfield

In my code I have:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)theTextField{

if (theTextField == ITload)
{
    [ITload resignFirstResponder];
    return  YES;
}

if (theTextField == FacilitiesLoad) {
    [FacilitiesLoad resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
return NO;
}
```

ITload and FacilitiesLoad are both my text fields. I'm using Numerical with punctuation keyboard and no done key appears. I have a return key which doesnt close the keyboard down.

Any ideas on how to display a done key and to get textFieldShouldReturn working please?

Comment: Have you set the delegate? `İTLoad.delegate = self;`

Comment: One more thing to note -- Objective C convention is that method & variable names should start with a lower case letter (i.e. "`itLoad`" and "`facilitiesLoad`") while class names should start with capitals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you haven't set the delegate of your text fields to your receiver.

```
ITLoad.delegate = self;
FacilitiesLoad.delegate = self;
```

EDIT: you're getting warnings because your view controller doesn't (formally) comforms to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. Declare it like this:

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
}
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks, what does this do? I'm also getting a warning:

http://picturepush.com/public/8905485