# Textfield value not being updated in time for save textFieldDidEndEditing

Tags: ios, core-data, uitextfield

I'm working on a simple app that uses Core Data. I have a detail screen with a textfield that I want to have saved when I click a done button. Right now, the done action is being completed before textFieldDidEndEditing is being called.

(Using xcode 6)

I can get the field input logged to the console. so I think I have the outlets set up correctly and the delegate relationships in place.

Here's what I believe to be the relevant code:

```
- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.seasonName = textField.text;
    NSLog(@"Did End Editing: %@", self.seasonName);
}

- (IBAction)done:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    Season *season = nil;

    if (self.seasonToEdit) {
        season = self.seasonToEdit;
    } else {
        season = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Season" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }

    season.seasonName = self.seasonName;
    //season.seasonDescription = self.seasonDescriptionTextView.text;

    NSLog(@"Season name: %@", season.seasonName);

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

As you can see from this log, I'm getting the message from the done action before the textfieldDidEndEditing call:

```
2014-10-08 16:36:10.318 ScorerCD[12277:475893] Season name: (null)
2014-10-08 16:36:10.842 ScorerCD[12277:475893] Did End Editing: the
```

Where is my problem?  Thanks.

Edited: I tried resignFirstResponder at top of done method with no impact. Also, I tried setting season.seasonName = self.seasonNameTextField.text with no change.

Another edit: If I use this code either with or without the self.seasonName = newText I see that the characters are being entered in the text field but self.seasonNameTextField.text remains null when I try to retrieve it.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newText = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    self.doneBarButton.enabled = ([newText length] > 0);

    NSLog(@"In change characters");

    self.seasonName = newText;

    return YES;
}
```

Edited: More log info

```
2014-10-09 09:46:33.280 ScorerCD[13179:517301] New Season
2014-10-09 09:46:37.788 ScorerCD[13179:517301] In change characters
2014-10-09 09:46:37.792 ScorerCD[13179:517301] In change characters
2014-10-09 09:46:42.104 ScorerCD[13179:517301] In change characters
2014-10-09 09:46:42.343 ScorerCD[13179:517301] In change characters
2014-10-09 09:46:42.627 ScorerCD[13179:517301] In change characters
2014-10-09 09:46:45.112 ScorerCD[13179:517301] Season to edit: (null)
2014-10-09 09:46:45.194 ScorerCD[13179:517301] Season: <Season: 0x7be3b7d0> (entity: Season; id: 0x7be323c0 <x-coredata:///Season/t7CBA137F-F348-47E6-A0EA-2518DAF422392> ; data: {
    games = nil;
    seasonDescription = nil;
    seasonName = nil;
})
2014-10-09 09:46:45.194 ScorerCD[13179:517301] Season name: (null)
2014-10-09 09:46:45.712 ScorerCD[13179:517301] In change characters
2014-10-09 09:46:45.744 ScorerCD[13179:517301] Did End Editing: the high
```

Edited: Here is my code in AppDelegate to create the MOC and pass it to the SeasonVC and the code that passes it to the SeasonFactsVC.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    SeasonsViewController *controller = navigationController.viewControllers[0];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    return YES;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.)
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    return _managedObjectContext;
}
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddSeason"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        SeasonFactsViewController *controller = (SeasonFactsViewController *) navigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        controller.seasonToEdit = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the outlet is attached in interface builder. I have added some code to my answer that should help

Comment: Out of interest, log out these and see what they return  NSLog(@"Season to edit: %@", self.seasonToEdit); NSLog(@"Season: %@", season);

Comment: @Tom Bates They both show as null I edited my question to show the log I get.

Comment: try   if (![self.seasonToEdit isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
        season = self.seasonToEdit;
    } else {
        season = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Season" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }

Comment: Also make sure you self.managedObjectContext isn't nil

Comment: @Tom Bates First suggestion makes no difference. Logging the MOC shows 2014-10-09 09:58:38.522 ScorerCD[13254:521361] MOC in viewDidLoad: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x786c18e0> I added my code above that relates to the MOC.  Thanks for al you help on this!

Comment: Which season = line does it hit? I would also take out the seasonToEdit = nil in the prepare for segue method

Comment: @Tom Bates taking out the line in prepareForSegue makes no difference. Not sure what you mean about the season = line

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think that it would make a difference. It's just not needed. In your if statement is it hitting the line that creates a new season or the one that makes the season = self.seasonToEdit??

Comment: @Tom Bates Hmm, hitting seasonTo Edit, which doesn't make sense to me, but either way I should have something in self.seasonNameTextField.text, shouldn't I?

Comment: You should. Change the if to if (self.seasonToEdit != nil) just to be sure otherwise I'd make the season when the view loads if I were you and update the name as the textfield changes its text using uitextfielddelegate

Comment: @Tom Bates  I ahd the delegate method in place, but if(self.seasonToEdit != nil) works.  Why doesn't either if(self.seasonToEdit) or your suggestion to test for null work? And why isn't the textfield value there in either case. Any ideas?  Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: the null issue is because it isnt null, its nil. The (self.seasonToEdit) issue I think is a new xcode 6 thing. Not sure about the text though. possibly change the outlet reference to strong but I doubt that is the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this the text field is being resigned as part of you dismissing the view controller at the end of the done method. Not before.
If you want to get the textfields text sooner you could link the field as an outlet and get the text value from that I.e self.mytextfield.text either that or call resignFirstResponder on the text field at the top of the done method.

**EDIT:**

create an outlet for your textfield (and link it to your textfield in interface builder):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextfield *seasonNameTextField;
```

then update your done method

```
- (IBAction)done:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    Season *season = nil;

    if (self.seasonToEdit != nil) {
        season = self.seasonToEdit;
    } else {
        season = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Season" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }

    season.seasonName = self.seasonNameTextField.text;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have that exact code, my outlet is connected (I can see it when I hover over the dot next to the IBOutlet statement) yet I stlll get a null self.seasonNameTextField.text I'm totaly baffled as your anser makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9101699/3096507

Basically `textFieldDidEndEditing` is called when the keyboard is dismissed. Which probably isn't until after you click the done button.

So you can either check your textField in your `done` method or use `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding both of these options and am still  getting a null self.seasonNameTextField.text. It's like the text firld value just isn't getting passed.

Answer (score 0):

You loose the Focus of your TextField AFTER you clicked on a new UI Control. So you will always have your Button function first called before the DidEndEdition will fire.

You could use

```
textViewDidChange
```

to update your seasonName

Answer (score 0):

`- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` gets called after your text field resign first responder which is after you click the save button so there is no problem with that. If you have the text field outlet why not directly check that and assign value?